# OrphanApp message in Health analyzer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, central-administration, health-analyzer, orphan

The health analyzer shows a lot of [OrphanApp] messages.
E.g.

```
[OrphanApp] App [d7cce181-a109-415d-9ee0-ff1f77d110c0] is orphaned in the database [xxx] on site collection [a702dcca-0c41-43f4-9fb3-9d604ecedb79].   
Orphaned Apps are not accessible, cause unnecessary resource and license consumption and may fail upgrade. Try to uninstall this App. 
App [d7cce181-a109-415d-9ee0-ff1f77d110c0] is orphaned in the database [xxx] on site collection [a702dcca-0c41-43f4-9fb3-9d604ecedb79]. 
Try to uninstall this App. If the App uninstallation is failing, it needs to be unblocked before the orphan App can be removed.
```

These sites with those ID's does not even exist anymore!
Also with the cmdlet Get-SPDeletedSite, I can't find any sites with those ID's.

Also with the cmdlets

```
$CDB = Get-SPContentDatabase -identity "GUID of the content database"  
$CDB.Repair($true)
```

It does not help anything. It even tells me

```
<OrphanedObjects Count="0" />
```

Does anybody knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell did not help...
Health Analyzer 'Repair Automatically' did not help... (saw errors in the ULS logs that it tries to access the site...that does not exists anymore and so cannot remove the app)
Only solution left: Remove those records from the AppInstallations table in the content database.